# Client side validation still causes POST in Chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, google-chrome

When I click submit I see that validation fails.  There are lots of red label errors.  However, the page still POSTs.  How can I make this thing fail client side?

***Note.  This issue is only happening in Chrome v33.0.  IE v10 and FF v26.0 do not do it.***  [Cookies are enabled for chrome](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/61416?hl=en).  Also, this issue does not happen when running the visual studio debugger.  The debugger is configured to use Local IIS server.  It only occurs on the development server.

I configured client side validation in the web.config:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```

My form looks like:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
   //fields....
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
}
```

And my references should be complete:

```
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/DataTables-1.9.4/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Themes/start/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css")" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/customItemRequestValidation.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/conditional-validation.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/CatalogScript.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: in firebug, enable **persist** and try the form submit and see whether you are getting any other javascript errors.

Comment: @Shyju - Well, in trying your suggestion I need to update the question.  This issue is only happening in CHROME.  IE and FF did not do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to windows 7 and Server 2008.  When I change the host to windows 8 (and I suspect server 2012) the issue is gone.  I've experienced similar problems with MVC in the past related to the version of IIS.  I know MVC modifies IIS.  So, I'm guessing here that there is a bug related to the version of IIS and how MVC works with IIS causing the problem.

To fix it I can either:

1. Change the host to IIS 8 (windows 8)
2. Rely solely on server side validation in this case.

Comment: Doing server side validation shouldn't be thought of as a way to get around this.  Even with client side validation working, server side validation should ALWAYS be done.  All you have to do is check ModelState.IsValid, and it will run the same checks as the client.

Comment: I agree with you.  Server side validation should be done regardless.  I just wish client side validation was possible.